# There's a way of send pushes from server side to devices by location?

Tags: c#, android, ios, iphone, cordova

There is a way to send pushes from the server code (in a ASP.NET app) according to geographic location (more less than a city) of a mobile device? (any device with an example to me is useful)

Thanks!

Comment: I prefer Iphone oriented response, but Android is useful to me too

Answer (score 6):

There is a way to send push notification by location, for this purpose i use PushApps, which is an SDK to manage push notifications.
They are suppose to support this option really soon (according to the support people), and they have a functional web site that supports lots of push actions...

go to http://www.pushapps.mobi/

they were extremely helpful with the implementation etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the user's location and also map with his gcm ID to be able to push geographically. There are no API's from google to do this.